# How to cast a Value* to a ConstantDataArray* in LLVM?

Tags: llvm

I extended the LLVM Kaleidoscope example to support Strings.  I added a StringExprAST, which has the virtual Codegen method impl as follows:

```
Value *StringExprAST::Codegen() {
  StringRef r(Val);
  return ConstantDataArray::getString(getGlobalContext(), r, false);
}
```

I am trying to concatenate Strings and have a ConcatExprAST with its Codegen method.  Upon trying to access the data in the ConstantDataArray, I need to cast the Value* back to a ConstantDataArray* in order to use the getAsString() method.

How can I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Doesn't `cast<ConstantDataArray>(v)` work?

Comment: if( ConstantDataArray * cda = dyn_cast<ConstantDataArray>(v) ) {
        StringRef r = cda->getAsString();

Comment: ConstantDataArray * cda = cast<ConstantDataArray>(v); throws this error:  Assertion failed: (isa<X>(Val) && "cast<Ty>() argument of incompatible type!"), function cast, file /Users/rcatlin1/lldb/llvm/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h, line 208.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to cast any subtype of `Value` to another is via `cast<>()`, e.g.:

```
Value* v = ...
ConstantDataArray* result = cast<ConstantDataArray>(v);
```

However, keep in mind that in your example you don't return an object of type `ConstantDataArray`, but you return something of the return type of `ConstantDataArray::getString()`, which is not necessarily an instance of `ConstantDataArray` itself, all you know is that it's a `Constant` (for instance, it might be a `ConstantAggregateZero`, which is not a `ConstantDataArray`).

In any case, if you're not sure that `v` is indeed of a specific type, check it first with `isa<>()` (or use [the `dyn_cast<>()` idiom](http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#the-isa-cast-and-dyn-cast-templates)), before performing the `cast<>()`.

Comment: cast<ConstantDataArray>(v) does work.  The problem turned out to be my input data.  Thanks for the above information about ConstantAggregateZero.